Trying to implement google captcha on microsoft exchange to prevent brute force
I'm trying to implement captcha on microsoft exchange, but they still brute forcing users, like they skip the captcha there.
the recaptcha file that i created have this code
<% @ Page AspCompat=True Language = "VB" %>
<%
Dim strPrivateKey As String = "KEY"
Dim strResponse = Request("response")
Dim objWinHTTP As Object
objWinHTTP = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
objWinHTTP.Open("POST", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", False)
objWinHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Dim strData As String = "secret=" & strPrivateKey & "&response=" & strResponse
objWinHTTP.Send(strData)
Dim strResponseText = objWinHTTP.ResponseText
Response.Write(strResponseText)
%>

at the logon this is the code i edited and added
<form **action=""** method="POST" name="logonForm" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="off">


<script type="text/javascript">
function myClkLgn()
{
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var sResponse = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value;
var sData = "response=" + sResponse;
oReq.open("GET", "/owa/auth/recaptcha.aspx?" + sData, false);
oReq.send(sData);
if (oReq.responseText.indexOf("true") != -1)
{
document.forms[0].action = "/owa/auth.owa";
clkLgn();
}
else
{
alert("Invalid CAPTCHA response");
}
}
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY"></div>


<div onclick="myClkLgn()" class="signinbutton" role="button" tabIndex="0" >



Everything works when clicking on the sign in button, but they still brute force..
Also i got this error code on recaptcha.aspx : { "success": false, "error-codes": [ "invalid-input-response" ] }
There is also hidden submit, i tired to do something with it, but didn't work.. still brute forcing..
